# Representing real numbers in $[0,1]$ with a binary tree

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

All we know Cantor's famous argument about counting real numbers in [0,1]. He basically suppose that we list every real number in [0,1] with a binary representation, then we use the diagonal argument to find a real number which is not listed there.

Let's think of an infinite binary tree. Root node is 0, and following every node has 0 as its left child and 1 as its right child. So, as far as I can see every branch of this tree corresponds to real number in [0,1] with a binary representation, which means that we can find every element in Cantor's list in this tree. Moreover, even the element constructed by diagonal argument can be found there.

If we count the nodes of this infinite binary tree, we have countable set since countable union of countable sets is countable. However, the set of infinite binary sequences is uncountable.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Counting nodes and counting branches is not the same. Even for finite trees.

Comment: Yes, of course. But, it is natural to think that number of branches cannot be greater than nodes. Perhaps we need to explain the relation ship between the number of notes and the number of branches.

Comment: Branches correspond to subsets. Nodes to elements. There are more subsets than elements, this is even true for finite sets.

Comment: Not all the subsets are included there. Basically, a binary tree with 7 nodes has 4 branches.

Comment: Yes, but last time I checked, 7 and 4 were different. So... why would you expect the nodes and branches of the binary tree to have the same cardinality?

Comment: For what it's worth, "number of nodes vs. number of branches" is the *wrong* analogue in the finite case; the point of a path in the infinite binary tree is that it's *complete*, whereas any finite node can still be extended in different ways. So the right (or better, anyways) analogue is to compare the number of non-terminal nodes and the number of terminal nodes, in a finite binary tree, since the terminal nodes are essentially the same thing as the paths in that case. Then we get that there is always one **more** terminal node than non-terminal node. (cont'd)

Comment: Of course, that's also beside the point. What must be understood is that lots of mathematics is counterintuitive (which is good for the employment of mathematicians!) - arguably our experience about finite trees should suggest that the set of reals is countable, but just because that's a reasonable guess doesn't make it true. Similarly, [our experience in topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) arguably suggests that there are more points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ than in $\mathbb{R}$, but that isn't true either.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real numbers in this tree do not correspond to nodes, they correspond to infinite chains starting at the root. There are uncountably many of those.

To prove that, you can mimic Cantor's diagonal argument. If the number of chains were countable you could list them
$$
C_1, C_2, 
\ldots
$$
Now build a chain $D$ that goes left at level $i$ (choice $0$) when $C_i$ goes right there (choice $1$) and vice versa. Then $D$ is a chain that's not in the list.

There really are more chains than nodes.

(Clever idea, that didn't quite work, as you suspected.)

Comment: How can we count these chains? In a finite binary tree, number of nodes greater than the number of branches. This confuses me.

Comment: @Cadenza See my edit.

Comment: I see it know, thanks.

Comment: That's only if we assume the list is not self aware such that it always adds each missing number and increments its own count when it does. My argument is that numbers are neural networks because the only interactions we have with numbers when they are neural networks. It's the assumption numbers are static entities that causes all these paradoxes...